# Android app to record Google Voice / Hangouts voice calls?

Tags: android, audio, voip, voice-recording, google-hangouts

Are there any Android apps that allow the user to record their VoIP voice calls (both directions) that are made through Google Voice / Google Hangouts?

Please assume consent has been provided by all parties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive searching and trying many different apps, I have concluded that there is currently no Android app that can accomplish this task.  I welcome all new answers if this should change (or if I'm mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

The "internal audio" recording feature of [SCR Screen Recorder](http://www.scr-screen-recorder.com/) should be helpful for this purpose. I don't have a device to test on at the moment, but (1) I assume it requires root. (2) I don't know if it will be possible to get both halves of the conversation by recording both the remote party and the local microphone audio. Perhaps this would require running two recording apps simultaneously.

Comment: *I don't know if it will be possible to get both halves of the conversation* That is an essential requirement, so whya re you suggesting this if you don't know?

Comment: I might not get around to trying. I just figured this is better than no information.