# VoIP client that allows recording calls

Tags: voip, voice-recording

There is no known way to easily record a Google Hangouts call (see [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18141/android-app-to-record-google-voice-hangouts-voice-calls)).

Are there any reliable VoIP clients that allow making free *outgoing* phone calls that either include recording capability, or that are compatible with other recording apps?

Note that supporting incoming calls is *not* required, but the ability to make outgoing calls through the POTS (Plain Old Telephone System) network *is* required (cannot *only* support VoIP-to-VoIP).

Prefer gratis, but a one-time payment for the app is acceptable.  No per-minute or monthly fees, please.

Support for either Android or Windows is needed.  Does not need to support both.